# 'DbContext has been disposed error' on Multiple Calls

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I've setup an API that has a simple `getCustomers()` method. The endpoint returns data on the first call, but returns an error on a second call.

> **Error:** The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed

The error is caused within my `CustomerService` on the `return db.Customers...`

> **Question:** Why does this work on the first call, but fail on the second call. How can this be resolved?

**GitHub Repo can be found here:** https://github.com/ChaseHardin/MyBookStore

**Here's a walkthrough of the code:**

**Controller:**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/customers")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    private readonly CustomerService _service = new CustomerService();

    [HttpGet, Route("")]
    public virtual IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var customers = _service.GetCustomers();
        return Ok(new {customers});
    }
}
```

**Customer Service:**

```
public class CustomerService : BaseService
{
    public List<CustomerViewModel> GetCustomers()
    {
        using (var db = Application.GetDatabaseInstance())
        {
            return db.Customers.Select(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel>).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseService**

```
public class BaseService
{
    public BaseService()
    {
        AutoMapperConfiguration();
    }

    public void AutoMapperConfiguration()
    {
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                 .GetTypes()
                 .Where(x => x.IsClass && x.Namespace == "MyBookStore.Business.ViewModels")
                 .ForEach(x => System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(x.TypeHandle));

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<bool, short?>().ConvertUsing(x => x ? (short)1 : (short)0);
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<short, bool>().ConvertUsing(x => x == 1);

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<bool, int?>().ConvertUsing(x => x ? 1 : 0);
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<int?, bool>().ConvertUsing(x => x.HasValue && x.Value == 1);

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<short, int>().ConvertUsing(x => (int)x);
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<int, int?>().ConvertUsing(x => x);
    }
}
```

**CustomerViewModel**

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    static CustomerViewModel()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>().ReverseMap();
    }

    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Context Setup:**

```
public class Application
{
    private static readonly MyBookStoreEntity Context = new MyBookStoreEntity();

    public static MyBookStoreEntity GetDatabaseInstance()
    {
        return Context;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your context is a singleton and you are disposing it after you use it.

Comment: You're using a static context inside a using statement, so use it once, then it gets disposed. Never use a static context!

Comment: A static database context is a *famously* bad idea.  You've discovered one of the reasons why.

Comment: Okay, so I removed the static database context and instantiate my `Application`. However, I'm still getting that DbContext error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Show how your code looks now.

Comment: Hey, I just fixed it... I forgot to remove the static from my entity object i.e. `private static readonly MyBookStoreEntity Context...`

Comment: Thank you for the help, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Now you understand, go read David's answer, upvote it and accept it!

Comment: Don't use `.Map()` with `IQuerable<T>` objects you should be using the [`Automapper.QueryableExtensions`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) namespace with the `.ProjectTo<T>()` function. ex: `return db.Customers.ProjectTo<CustomerViewModel>().ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a `using` block:

```
using (var db = Application.GetDatabaseInstance())
```

The object being "used" will be disposed at the end of the block.  (`using` is basically syntactic shorthand for a `try/finally` where the `finally` block calls `.Dispose()` on the object.)

And what you're "using" is this value:

```
private static readonly MyBookStoreEntity Context = new MyBookStoreEntity();
```

This value is `static`, so it's the same instance of `MyBookStoreEntity` every time it's called.  But when you call it the first time, you `.Dispose()` it.  So any subsequent calls will be on a disposed object.

Basically, you've discovered one of the reasons why a `static` database context is a *very* bad idea.  You can still encapsulate your database context into a method like you have, but make the method return a new instance each time:

```
public static MyBookStoreEntity GetDatabaseInstance()
{
    return new MyBookStoreEntity();
}
```

Or, if that method isn't really providing any benefit at this point, then just create the context where you need it:

```
using (var db = new MyBookStoreEntity())
```

Creating a database context isn't a particularly heavy operation.  But keeping them around when you're not using them is.  (And sharing them among different operations is fraught with peril.)  A good rule of thumb is to discretely define the database operations you need to perform for a given application operation, and to create/use/dispose your database connection in as tight a code block around those operations as possible.